Nginx and wordpress PHPSESSID sometimes with leading dot
On my server I have with nginx

A Wordpress on the domain : https://www.test.com
A Symfony on the same domain : https://www.test.com/app

My issue is that my PHPSESSID sometimes have the domain :

.www.test.com
www.test.com

The one with the leading dot is causing issue with Symfony login.
Is there a way to force the cookie domain to always be www.test.com ?
